# Multiple transitions between states with TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create two transitions between states while using the TiKZ library for automata drawing.

Currently, I have this example code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm]
    \node[state] (A)                {A};
    \node[state] (B) [right of = A] {B};
    \path[->] (A) edge [bend left]  node {x = 0} (B)
              (B) edge [bend right] node {x = 1} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following result :

[image: My ugly FSM]

I'd like to have two arrows between the states instead : one with `x = 0`, and the second one with `x = 1`.

How can I do that with TiKZ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). And thanks for providing a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is sometimes difficult to get one from some who have been here for a while, so it is really great to see it from a new user.

Comment: It's good to know that I made a good first impression. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using`bend left` for *both* edges yields:

[image]

### Notes;

- The `bend left`, `bend right` direction is relative to the direction of the edge. If *both* edges were from `A` to `B`, the `bend left`, `bend right` would work. But, in this case since one is from `A` to `B`, and the other is from `B` to `A`, then both need to `bend left` to obtain the desired results.
- Math content should *always* be in math mode. See changes made in MWE related to the labels for the edges.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=4cm]
    \node[state] (A)                {A};
    \node[state] (B) [right of = A] {B};
    \path[->] (A) edge [bend left]  node {$x = 0$} (B)
              (B) edge [bend left] node {$x = 1$} (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```